# Paint Bucket function code in C# ,hangs when running,

Tags: c#, stack, paint, bucket

I try to use stack class for paint bucket function ,but when running and clicking on selected area in picture box  to be filled with selected color,nothing happens and cpu usage goes up to  %100 and system hangs!
here is the code,first, picture box code for selecting this function and call fill function after clicking:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (act == "color")
            {

                fill(bmp ,e.X, e.Y, bmp.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y));
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

            }

        }
```

============================and fill fuction which deosn't work!

```
private void fill(Bitmap picture, int x, int y, Color bcolor)
        {

            if (x > 0 && x < picture.Width && y > 0 && y < picture.Height)
            {

                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                Stack<Point> s = new Stack<Point>();
                s.Push(p);
                while (s.Count > 0)
                {
                    p = s.Pop();
                    Color currentcolor = picture.GetPixel(p.X, p.Y);
                    if (currentcolor == bcolor)
                    {
                        //this.Refresh();
                        picture.SetPixel(p.X, p.Y, currentcolor);
                        s.Push(new Point(p.X - 1, p.Y));
                        s.Push(new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y));
                        s.Push(new Point(p.X, p.Y - 1));
                        s.Push(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 1));
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

any idea to fix this issue?
thanks

---Actually I removed "this.Refresh()" code ,but still same result ,nothing changed! So ,any suggestion for correcting or a better code for paint bucket?

Comment: what is the reason to use  while (s.Count > 0)

Comment: Try taking the this.Refresh() outside of the while loop.

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker - He's `Push`ing and `Pop`ping so I suspect that the `s.Count > 0` is fine.

Comment: Are you expecting the UI to update with the `this.Refresh()`?

Comment: This code is likely to push more to the stack than it pops from it and therefore your loop might run endlessly (until the mem is filled up). As others mentioned, calling Refresh() might not be a good idea while you paint on a resource you want to use as image in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call this:

```
                    s.Push(new Point(p.X - 1, p.Y));
                    s.Push(new Point(p.X + 1, p.Y));
                    s.Push(new Point(p.X, p.Y - 1));
                    s.Push(new Point(p.X, p.Y + 1));
```

...without checking if each `p.X +/- 1` && `p.Y +/- 1` is within the bounds of the `Bitmap` otherwise for each pixel you pop you'll be pushing 4. That's going to grow the stack until you run out of memory.

The `this.Refresh()` is probably making the code run so slowly that you don't see the actual memory run out - hence the 100% CPU. You should remove the `this.Refresh()` because your UI can't update until the `fill` method completes anyway.

Comment: @Joey - You're spot on. I should have said that the `Stack` would grow until memory ran out.

Comment: so ,what algorithm do you suggest for paint buck ?
maybe I should change the entire code!

Comment: @Bardia225 - All you need to do is check the bounds of each `new Point` before you add them to the stack. And get rid of the `this.Refresh()`.